# QGIS 3.4. project file editing

Tags: qgis, editing, xml, file-formats

How can I edit a QGIS project file so that it would open, save and edit data from given folder and save the results for different directory? Kind of like MapInfo's Wor. file.

I read from QGIS manual that the project file is saved in a XML format, but for some reason I can't open it.

Comment: Could you please be more clear what exactly you are trying to achieve? Espescially for people who do not know the .wor file format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unzip Qgz file first. Then you can edit the qgs file with any text editor.